# Array intersection type loses the intersection in map()

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript code snippet and I'm having a problem with my mapped type losing intersection type information inside the `map()`.

```
type Foo = { foo: number };
type Bar = { bar: string };

const arr: Foo[] & Bar[] = [{ foo: 1, bar: 'bar' }];
// const arr: (Foo & Bar)[] = [{ foo: 1, bar: 'bar' }]; // Working version

const item = arr[0]; // item: Foo & Bar
item.bar.length; // 3

arr.map((item) => item.bar.length); // item: Foo. Why?
```

Here's the issue: when I access arr[0], it correctly has type Foo & Bar. However, inside the map() function, the type of item is Foo. This results in a type error when I try to access item.bar.length.

Why is TypeScript losing the intersection type information for items inside the `map()` function? How can I ensure that both the `Foo` and `Bar` properties are maintained in the type? Although the commented-out version works, I'd like to understand the issue with the original code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've commented out a working version of the code using the correct type `(Foo & Bar)[]`, but I'm confused as to why the original code doesn't maintain the intersection type information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue described in [ms/TS#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874).

From the issue:

> Array intersection is weird since there are many invariants of arrays and many invariants of intersections that can't be simultaneously met. For example, if it's valid to call `a.push(x)` when `a` is `A`, then it should be valid to write `ab.push(x)` when ab is `A & B`, but that creates an unsound read on `(A & B)[number]`.
> In higher-order the current behavior is really the best we can do; in zero-order, it's really preferable to just write `Array<A & B>`, `Array<A> | Array<B>`, or `Array<A | B>` depending on which you mean to happen.

Another quote from the [ms/TS/#11961](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11961):

> it's really unclear how `type TU = T[] & U[]` should be interpreted -- is it a heterogeneous array, the same as `Array<T | U>` ? Or the same as `Array<T & U>` ? An axiom is that for any operation `x.y(z)`, that should still be legal for `x` if `x` becomes an intersection type containing the original constituent, but that wouldn't be true if we interpreted the array to be `Array<T & U>` (since `z` would have to be the intersected element type as well). So overall... probably a bad idea to have the type `T[] & U[]` floating around.

Basically, this is the most reasonable solution:

```
(Foo & Bar)[]
```